# Pagination with Django and Nuxt 3

Tags: python, django, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I use Django for backend and nuxt3 for frontend
My problem is that:

Error when I use pagination in Django:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

But without activating pagination, it shows my content without any problem

Thank you

my code :

**index.vue**

```
<template>
    <h1>test</h1>
    <div v-for="portfolio in portfolios" :key="portfolio.id">
        <h1>{{ portfolio.title }}</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="pagination">
        <ul class="inline-flex">
            <li>
                <button class="c-pointer">
                    <svg><use href="#arrowbefore"></use></svg>
                </button>
            </li>
            <li>
                <button class="c-pointer">
                    <svg><use href="#arrownext"></use></svg>
                </button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>
<script setup>

const { public: {apiURL} } = useRuntimeConfig();
const { data: portfolios, refresh } = await useFetch(`${apiURL}/portfolio`);

</script>
```

**views.py**

```
class PortfolioApiViewPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 1


class PortfolioApiView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Portfolio.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PortfolioSerializer
    pagination_class = PortfolioApiViewPagination
```

**settings.py**

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 8
}
```

Please tell me the best solution

Comment: Can you show the error log in your django backend?

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: I guess that is error is showing on the client side , can you show the error log in your django environment aka ( manage.py runserver / or gunicorn or any wsgi server your are using )

Comment: `the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)` This is generic, without seeing the actual log from the backend server it is hard to determine what is going wrong in your django server

Comment: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'title')